# Email template issue Craft Contact Form Extensions

Tags: craft3, emails, plugin-contactformextensions

I am using Contact Form Extensions plugin https://github.com/Rias500/craft-contact-form-extensions for setting up custom notification email template but not sure what tag would be used for additional fields like `Phone`.
Here is my code sample:

```
<p>Name: {{ submission.fromName }}</p>
<p>Company: {{ submission.Company }}</p>
<p>Name: {{ submission.fromEmail }}</p>
<p>Phone: {{ submission.Phone }}</p>
<p>Type of Enquiry: {{ submission.typeOfEnquiry }}</p>
<p>Message: {{ submission.message }}</p>
```

Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
{{ submission.message.Phone }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and the following worked for me:

```
<p>Phone: {{ submission.message['Phone'] }}</p>
<p>Message: {{ submission.message['body'] }}</p>
```